# Is it possible in ASP.NET Core to enable XmlSerialization for a single controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, xmlserializer

I have a Web API that has several controllers, one of which returns XML for legacy reasons, while all the others return JSON.

In a .NET Framework I can selectively enable XML serialization for a single controller by accessing `HttpControllerSettings.Formatters` (typically in an attribute used to decorate the controller).

Is it possible to do the same in ASP.NET Core, i.e. only enable Xml serialization for a single controller?

The only way I've found to enable Xml serialization in ASP.NET Core 2.1 is globally, using:

```
services.AddMvc()
     .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
     .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

This works OK, but has a side-effect that I consider to be undesirable: when I run the application in Visual Studio I see a trace of an warning from `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` something like:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerOutputFormatter:Warning: An error occurred while trying to create an XmlSerializer for the type 'MyApp.MyModel'.

System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'MyApp.MyModel'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member ... see inner exception for more details. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize ... because it is an interface.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type)
   ...
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerOutputFormatter.CreateSerializer(Type type)
```

It appears to be trying to create an `XmlSerializer` for a Type that is not used by my "XML" controller.

While it's not a showstopper, I'd prefer not to be creating XmlSerializers except when I need them.

Comment: When I response `mymodel` as xml,it would generate such error like your warning.But if i do not response the model as xml,it would not get such warning.Could you share a sample that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Rena, I am returning an `ActionResult<MyModel>` from an action in a different controller that is decorated with `[Produces("application/json")]`.  But the controller that returns XML only has actions that return `ActionResult<object>` (where object is in fact an XmlDocument).

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same issue. I do not believe there is a solution at the moment, so I've created [a feature request on the Github project](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25573).

In the meantime, I've set

```
"Logging": { 
    "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerOutputFormatter":  "Error"
    }
}
```

To suppress the warnings during startup.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue.Then I changed my code:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

[U can check this one out](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13121), I hope it's has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Solved by setting Produces attribute to application/json on the action that caused the issue.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("yourroute")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult<Whatever> GetSomething() {
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not an "in box" way to do this, short of manually serializing and returning via `FileContentResult` or similar.  However, you can add a "marker" class and formatters which specially handle the marker class.

Steps are:

1. Define a marker wrapper struct which wraps the value to be serialized/deserialized. 
   <sub>([Example Implementation](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/blob/master/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/IByXmlSerializer.cs))</sub>
2. Define a `TextInputFormatter`/`TextOutputFormatter` which read/write your marker class using `XmlSerializable`. 
   <sub>([MSDN Guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-8.0), [Example Input Implementation](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/blob/master/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/ByXmlSerializerInputFormatter.cs), [Example Output Implementation](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/blob/master/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/ByXmlSerializerOutputFormatter.cs))</sub>
3. Register the formatters earlier in the list than DCS in `MvcOptions`. 
   <sub>([Example Implementation](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/blob/master/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/ByXmlSerializerExtensions.cs#L19))</sub>
4. Optionally: Add a `JsonConverter` to the marker class to make it invisible to JSON

An implementation of this is available in [Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer), MIT Licensed).  [Example use](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer/tree/master/DemoApp):

```cs
// Add Nuget reference to Rmg.AspNetCore.ByXmlSerializer

// in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddByXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

// in controller
[HttpGet("xs")]
public ByXmlSerializer<WeatherForecast[]> GetWeatherForecastXmlSerializer()
{
    WeatherForecast[] result = /* ... */;
    return result;
}

// or for input
[HttpPost("postxs")]
public void PostWeatherForecastXs([FromBody] ByXmlSerializer<ForecastArea> area)
{
    // ...
}
```